# What's the best way to split a string into integer part and string part?

Tags: python, regex, string

I am having a string like this "11547QSD". I would like to split it in to 2 parts "11547" and "QSD". I got a hint with isnumeric() function. I am placing a overview down.Please suggest me a best way to split this.

```
 str1 = "11547QSD"    # is a valid string (in my context)
 str2 = "ABC98765"    # is a valid string
 str3 = "111ABC111"   # is not a valid string

 if str1.isvalid():
    str1_int = str1.integer_part()
    str1_str = str1.string_part()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest you to solve it in the "naive" way, unless you are accustomed to imperative programming and want to use python-tricks. iterate over it, find the points where it changes from `isnumeric()` to `isalpha()`, make sure it is a single point, and split it there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regular expressions with named groups.

You basically first create regular expressions (I created two, for both cases: digits first or letters first). Then you check if the input matches. If it does, you call `groupdict()` on the resulting match object to get dictionary like `{'digits':'11547', 'letters':'QSD'}`. Then you just use it (I printed it).

Full example following the above advice:

```
>>> import re
>>> checks = [
    re.compile(r'^(?P<digits>\d+)(?P<letters>\D+)$'),
    re.compile(r'^(?P<letters>\D+)(?P<digits>\d+)$'),
]
>>> inputs = ['11547QSD', 'ABC98765', '111ABC111']
>>> for item in inputs:
    for check in checks:
        if check.match(item):
            print('Digits are {digits}, letters are {letters}'.format(
                **check.search(item).groupdict()
            ))
            break
    else:
        print('%s is incorrect' % (item,))


Digits are 11547, letters are QSD
Digits are 98765, letters are ABC
111ABC111 is incorrect
```

### Shortened version

If you understand the above, you can shorten the code and create the resulting dict (matching string - resulting groups) like that:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> {item: check.search(item).groupdict()
     for (item, check) in product(inputs, checks) if check.match(item)}
{'ABC98765': {'digits': '98765', 'letters': 'ABC'},
'11547QSD': {'digits': '11547', 'letters': 'QSD'}}
```

**Note**:

I used metacharacters `\d` and `\D`. The first basically means "digit", the second means "non-digit". The details on what they mean are [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Answer (score 0):

I think regex should be the best solution, an example:

`import re

re.split(r'(\d+|\(|\))', '11547QSD')`

Comment: this returns a list with the first item being blank quotations: `['', '11547', 'QSD']`. I'm not familiar with regex, but how could you remove that in the expression rather than adding a `[1:]` at the end

Answer (score 0):

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits
s_int, s_str = sorted([s.strip(ascii_letters), s.strip(digits)])
is_valid = s in {s_int+s_str, s_str+s_int}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mostly for fun:

```
ss  = ["11547QSD", "ABC98765", "111ABC111"]

fmt = r'\A(?P<full>{0}{1})\Z'
ps  = [r'(?P<digits>\d+)', r'(?P<letters>[A-Z]+)']

fs  = [fmt.format(*sorted(ps, reverse = b)) for b in [False, True]]
rs  = [re.compile(f) for f in fs]
ms  = filter(None, (r.search(s) for s in ss for r in rs))
gds = [m.groupdict() for m in ms]

for gd in gds:
    print gd

# Output:
# {'digits': '11547', 'full': '11547QSD', 'letters': 'QSD'}
# {'digits': '98765', 'full': 'ABC98765', 'letters': 'ABC'}
```